# How do I host an HTTP proxy?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-proxy

I am using Requests to scrape a website. My scraping code runs on one computer, but I need to make the requests come from a different computer (from the perspective of the website being scraped). I understand that I can do this with Requests by passing a [`proxies=` argument](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) when creating my session. I understand that I have two options, either using an HTTP proxy or a SOCKS proxy. I understand how to host an SOCKS proxy, because it just works over SSH, so I just need to make it so that I can SSH into the proxy machine from the machine running the scraping code and use `-D`, like this

```sh
# Generate key
ssh-keygen -o -a 100 -t ed25519 -C ''
# Copy key to proxy machine
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub <username>@<ip of the computer acting as a proxy>
# Open a connection to that server on some local port (I randomly chose port 14171)
ssh -D 14171 root@<ip of the computer acting as a proxy>
```

then I can make requests like this

```py
from requests import Session

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://localhost:14171',
    'https': 'socks5://localhost:14171',
}

session = Session()
session.proxies.update(proxies)

session.get('http://example.com')
```

I understand that with an HTTP proxy it's quite similar, I just do

```py
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:1080',
    'https': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:1080',
}
```

but what do I use on the server to make it act as an HTTP proxy with a password? And are messages sent in the clear or encrypted?

Comment: Question is not clear, tbh. "are messages sent in the clear or encrypted" - I assume that site you are scraping using HTTPS protocol, so requests will be encrypted with SSL.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I'm asking if the messages to the proxy server from my scraping code are encrypted. They are when using SOCKS obviously, because that uses SSH, but do I (how do I) get the same security using an HTTP proxy? Would an eavesdropper be able to see the HTTP proxy's password?

Comment: It depends on method how proxy server get auth data. When you're using HTTP proxy, authorization passed in [`Proxy-Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization) header. 99,9% of proxies using `Basic` scheme which is just `base64(username:password)` so if your traffic will be dumped it's easy to extract auth data.

Answer (score 2):

There are many implementations of HTTP proxies to choose from. [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) seems to be the first result on Google. I also tried [Tinyproxy](http://tinyproxy.github.io/). With Squid, you set it up like this:

Install Squid

```sh
apt install squid apache2-utils
```

Create the password file

```sh
sudo touch /etc/squid/squid_passwd
sudo chown proxy /etc/squid/squid_passwd
```

Then edit the configuration file

```sh
mv /etc/squid/squid.conf /etc/squid/squid.conf.default # move default file out of the way
vim /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

and paste the following as the configuration:

```
http_port 3128

auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/squid_passwd
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
```

you can add those lines to the end of the file, but the problem is that their default config is 8000 lines of documentation (about 25 lines of actual default config) and somewhere in there they forbid all connections (probably all connections not from localhost) that you'd have to read and ain't nobody got time for that, so I just cleared and put that config as the default. You should probably take the time to actually learn Squid if you're going to use it though...

Create a password for a user (`youruser` is a username, you can choose whatever)

```sh
htpasswd /etc/squid/squid_passwd youruser
```

Restart Squid

```sh
service squid restart
```

Open the port in the firewall

```sh
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
```

You can then check that it works with [Curl](https://curl.se/docs/manual.html):

```sh
curl --proxy <the IP address of your proxy>:3128 --proxy-user youruser:<password> "http://icanhazip.com"
```

---

[Tinyproxy](http://tinyproxy.github.io/) is pretty similar, it has the advantage that you don't have to download a separate package just to set a password and their default config file is actually short enough to read...

Install Tinyproxy

```
sudo apt install tinyproxy
```

Edit the config file

```
sudo vim /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf
```

These are the options I needed to set:

1. change the port to some random port `Port 17724`
2. comment out the `Allow 127.0.0.1` line to allow connections from any IP
3. add a line to enable a password `BasicAuth youruser yourpassword`
4. (optional) disable adding a ["Via" header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Via) (this is a way to let servers that you're making requests to know that you're using a proxy) with `DisableViaHeader yes`
5. (optional) disable everything except for reverse-proxying with `ReverseOnly Yes`

You may want to read through the entire default config file, maybe there are other options you need for your use-case.

Restart the Tinyproxy systemd service

```
sudo service tinyproxy restart
```

Open the port in the firewall

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 17724 -j ACCEPT
```

---

The you can then use your proxy with Requests like this

```py
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://<youruser>:<password>@<the IP address of your proxy>:3128',
    'https': 'http://<youruser>:<password>@<the IP address of your proxy>:3128'
}
```

Proxies also allow you to limit connections to only a give IP address, so if the server you're running the code on has a static IP, it would be a good idea to limit connections only from that IP. Note that HTTP proxying is not encrypted, so a man-in-the-middle would be able to see your password and then use your proxy.

Sources:

- https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-squid-proxy-on-centos
- https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-squid-proxy-on-ubuntu (a bit outdated)